# Debugging slow loading Control Panel (and front-end too)

Tags: craft4, debug

Craft CMS  take a very long time to load, sometimes over 5-6 seconds (in my local environment WAMP).

Profiling with Yii Toolbar I can see that (a page in the Control Panel) :
[image]

The site is running Craft CMS 4.3.6.1.

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: I'd begin by going through this as a starting point: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/troubleshooting-performance-issues

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had looked at this page but I did not find any solutions.
The problem is not with the database. Queries run very quickly.
It seems to come from the configuration of the CMS or Apache